# Jetpack Compose v1.5.8 (2024.02.00) is very buggy - basic functionality no longer works

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

My Jetpack Compose v1.5.8 (BOM 2024.02.00) function fails to re-render `Text()`.
I narrowed the problem down to `Text()` component itself being the problem and not my code.

I have a `HashSet` to which I'm adding and removing values and I verified that `SomeClass` part works flawlessly:

```
class SomeClass {
    companion object {
        val mySet = MutableStateFlow(HashSet<String>())
    }

    fun add() {
        mySet.value.add("test")

        withReassign()
    }

    fun remove() {
        mySet.value.remove("test")

        withReassign()
    }

    // Just for test I also tried re-assigning entire set but this doesn't make Compose work either
    fun withReassign() {
        mySet.value = HashSet(mySet.value)
    }
}
```

What is also working flawlessly is logging the current size of the set with a `Button` but `Text` simply won't update or updates inconsistently:

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val test1 by SomeClass.mySet.collectAsState()
    val test2 = remember { mutableStateOf(test1.size) }

    Text("Test 1: ${test1}") // Doesn't refresh consistently or sometimes it's stuck at "0" or "1" forever
    Text("Test 2: ${test2.value}") // Extracting size to a separate variable doesn't help

    // Inside Button logging both values are always correct
    Button(
        onClick = {
            Log.i("TAG", "Real current size: ${SomeClass.mySet.value.size}, compose current size: ${test1.size}")
        }
    ) {
        Text("Log set size")
    }
}
```

So, I'm 99% sure Compose v1.5.8 (BOM 2024.02.00) is broken (`Text()` gets the correct value but doesn't refresh), but in case I'm missing something I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: I fixed this by creating another variable in `SomeClass` that is an integer. Here is the fix: `val stringsCount = MutableStateFlow(0)`. Compose doesn't work with `HashSet` but it works with plain integer for me.

Comment: Your use of the StateFlow seems odd to me — certainly not representative of "basic functionality". 

If you just want a Flow of String values, you might just `emit` them to the flow. And if you really want a Set of Strings, it seems to me that you should work with an immutable copy each time. Pre-process the Set as you need on each update, then `emit` the new immutable copy to the Flow. You might see more reliable behavior.

Comment: Thanks, the example has been simplified. In production code I'm using `HashSet` of other class instances, not strings. And my `HashSet` is populated by external API that only has `added()` and `removed()` callbacks and whose documentation says to keep track of what has been added and removed in the app because current state can't be accessed otherwise.

Comment: You might consider decoupling from the HashSet that is populated by the external API from this. Listen for the `added()` and `removed()` callbacks somewhere, but use a different, hopefully immutable data structure to populate the `StateFlow` for Compose. That will likely behave more reliably.